# Construct special "joint SVD" from separate SVDs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factorization

Given two matrices, $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ which can be written as

$$ A =  XD_AY^T \\
B = XD_BY^T $$

where $X$ and $Y\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are unitary and with diagonal $D_A$ and $D_B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ so that $(D_{A,B})_{ii} > 0$, is it possible to write $X$ and $Y$ in terms of the independent SVDS $A = RD_AS^T$ and $B=UD_BV^T$? The problem here is that the independent SVDs are not generally unique.

In other words, I am looking to express $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $R$, $S$, $U$ and $V$.

Comment: The two given decomposition are SVDs of $A$ and $B$, so this question as-is seems to be pre-solved. Is the intended question actually "given SVDs of $A$ and $B$, how can you find a joint SVD (assuming one exists)?"

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Yes, that was my intention, I will rephrase that.

Comment: If you have more freedom on the SVDs to compute, a common trick is computing the SVD of a random linear combination $\alpha A + \beta B$ instead. This SVD will give you working $X$ and $Y$ with probability 1 (in exact arithmetic).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Interesting. I already thought about using linear combinations. Do you have some more information on this trick?

Comment: @sqrt6 Not much unfortunately; I know it as a 'street trick' but I cannot point to a full analysis. Just https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951313/simultaneous-diagonalisation-of-matrices-by-diagonalising-a-random-linear-combin .

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I see. While this works of course, I was hoping to find a solution which also solves a much broader set of problems...

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422129) is closer to what I need...

Comment: I have just listened to a [talk by Daniel Kressner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-qC1IvCn9U) in which they analyze the stability of the 'street trick' for joint diagonalization of symmetric matrices. He said that a joint paper with Haoze He is in preparation.