# A gsvd variation: Two SVDs with common matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, factorization

The generalized singular value decomposition (gsvd) is described on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_singular_value_decomposition). Since there are several conventions, I'll just briefly present one.

The "MATLAB" convention decomposes two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ as follows:

$$ 
    A_1 = U_1 \Sigma_1 X^* \\
    A_2 = U_2 \Sigma_2 X^*
$$

with
$$ 
    U_i\ \text{unitary} \tag{1} \\
$$ $$
    \Sigma_i\ \text{positive diagonal} \tag{2} \\
$$ $$
    \Sigma_1^* \Sigma_1 + \Sigma_2^* \Sigma_2 = I \tag{3} \\
$$
and finally $X$ is "some matrix".

I am looking for a very similar decomposition but without restriction (3) and where $X$ is also unitary. In other words, these are just two regular SVDs of two matrices but they share a common matrix $X$. Is there maybe a way to construct this from the gsvd as defined above or another way to obtain these matrices, maybe from the separate SVDs? (If required you can assume that $A_1$ and $A_2$ support such a factorization.)

Comment: How do you know that $A_1$ and $A_2$ will have a common set of right singular vectors? For instance, consider $A_1 = [0] \oplus [1]$ and $A_2 = P A_1 P^{-1}$ where $P$ is a 45 degree rotation.

Comment: OK, so you're only considering this in cases where the factorisation exists. Got it.

Comment: In many cases, the set of left & right singular vectors should be unique (modulo signed permutation). So you can do $A_1 A_2^*$, take the SVD, and so obtain $U_1$ and $U_2$ up to signed permutation

Comment: Specifically, the above should work (up to signed permutation) if $A_1 A_2^*$ has no singular value clashes

Comment: Once $U_i P$ is obtained (where $P$ is a signed permutation) then $(U_i P)^{-1} A_i = P^T \Sigma_i X^*$. So the rows should be orthogonal.

Comment: Related earlier question from the same user https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422070/construct-special-joint-svd-from-separate-svds